# GIF to VIF in Twitter

Tags: video, twitter, gif, mp4

I hear that twitter now supports GIF format. But instead of using GIF directly, they converted to VIF(video format mp4)?

1. Why do they do it?
2. How do they do it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question is answered in [what I'm guessing is your source](http://blog.embed.ly/post/89265229166/what-twitter-isnt-telling-you-about-gifs).

> #### Compression
>
> GIFs are terrible at compression.
>
> #### Control
>
> Pausing a GIF isn’t really possible.

There's a good chance that Twitter is using [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) to do it, based on its popularity and reputation for being reliable. Also, I looked at the file header and it is very similar to videos I have encoded using FFmpeg.